# How to pass div element value to input type textbox and save value in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created one IMS System in that i have to do conversion of net_amount from number format to word format.I am getting proper output but it is in div element now i have to pass into input type text and after that i have to enter this value in database also.If anybody has any idea how to do it please help.
Below i have given my code (in this i am able to convert from div element to input type text box when i click on div value but value of input type is not entering in database)

```
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="words"><b>Total Net Amount(In Words):-</b></p>
                    <div id="container" class="conversion"></div><input type="hidden" name="net_amount_words" id="net_amount_words_Hidden"/>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#container").click(function(){ 
                        //check if there are any existing input elements
                        if ($(this).children('input').length == 0){
                        $("#saveFirstName").css("display", "inline");
                        //variable that contains input HTML to replace
                        var inputbox = "<input type='text' class='inputbox' name='net_amount_words' value=\""+$(this).text()+"\">";    
                        //insert the HTML intp the div
                        $(this).html(inputbox);         
                        //automatically give focus to the input box     
                        //$("this .inputbox").focus();
                        //maintain the input when it changes back to a div
                        $("this .inputbox").blur(function(){
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        $("#net_amount_words_Hidden").val(value);
                      });
                    }               
                 });
                </script>
```

Below is my query to insert data into database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $net_amount_words = $_POST['net_amount_words'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` SET `net_amount_words`='$net_amount_words' ";
        $_dbConn->insert($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Comment: why are you print $sql you just write mysqli_query($conn,$sql)                  //$conn is a database conection which define in above

Comment: I have updated my sql code